# Is using the Factory pattern make sense here?

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I have a PageItem object that I want to possibly reuse elsewhere.
I'm in ABC framework.

Here's the PageItem interface :

```
public interface PageItem {

    public abstract String getUrl();

    public abstract boolean getIsCurrent();

    public abstract PageItem getParent();

    public abstract List<PageItem> getPChildren();

    public abstract void setParent(PageItem pageItem);

    public abstract void addChild(PageItem pageItems);

    public abstract boolean getHasSelectedChild();

}
```

Here's the implementation :

```
public class PageItemImpl implements PageItem {

    private String title = "";
    private String url = "";
    private boolean isCurrent = false;
    private List<PageItem> children = new ArrayList<PageItem>();
    private PageItem parent = null;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public boolean getIsCurrent() {
        return isCurrent;
    }

    public List<PageItem> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }


    public PageItem getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setIsCurrent(boolean isCurrent) {
        this.isCurrent = isCurrent;
    }

    public void setParent(PageItem parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(PageItem pageItem) {
       this.children.add(pageItem);        
    }

    public boolean getHasSelectedChild() {        
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here's the factory :

```
public class PageItemFactory {

    public static PageItem getPageItem(ABCPage page,  ABCRequestParams params) throws ABCException {
        PageItemImpl pageItem = new PageItemABCImpl();
            pageItem.setTitle(page.getTitle());
            pageItem.setUrl(page.getUrl());  
            pageItem.setIsCurrent(params.getUrl().equals(page.getUrl());      
        return pageItem;
    }

}
```

Is that me or it doesn't make sense?

PageItemFactory won't be reusable elsewhere since it has references to ABC framework.

Should I just make a class that overrides PageItem and use a constructor for ABC specific parameters?

Comment: In my opinion the factory is not necessary here since the construction of the object is rather simple.

Comment: What layer is the ABCFramework supposed to sit inside?  View, Controller, etc.

Comment: Yep that's a basic Factory pattern, (Rename PageItem IPageItem would make it a bit clearer in most other devs eyes). To get the next level of abstraction, you should look at an IOC, (Inversion of Control) pattern implementation such as Dependency Injection.

Comment: That was an example but it'll be more complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends. There are two main reasons to have a factory:

1. The object setup is complex.
2. You need to translate between two independent parts of your application.

In the first case, the factory knows how to initialize an object so it can be used right away. In the second case, the factory works like a adapter/converter (converts one object type into another).

Reuse doesn't matter - in this case, it separates concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code calling the factory is intimately familiar with ABCPage using a Factory doesn't offer much improvement over invoking a constructor itself.

Where the factory pattern comes into it's own is where you want to create different subclasses of, in this case, PageItem, based more on the values of the arguments than their types.

e.g. If you had something like:

```
PageItem pi = PageItemFactory.
    createPageItem(Map<String, Object> data);
```

And the subclass of PageItem you wanted to return was determined by one of the values (or combination of values) in data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it re-usable for other types of PageItems you're going to need an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Your PageItemFactory would be an instance of an AbstractPageItemFactory, which could be reused. This would allow you to change the type of factory used by a method by passing in a different instance of the AbstractPageItemFactory.